# What is the __lt__ actually doing for lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

Say I have two lists, and I run the following command

```
>>> s = [1, 2, 3]
>>> t = [1, 2, 4]
>>> s > t
False
>>> s < t
True
```

But if I were to run the following command

```
>>> s = [1, 2, 3]
>>> t = [1, 1, 4]
>>> s > t
True
>>> s < t
False
```

Have to admit, I'm not too familiar with the PY3 codebase.  What exactly is going on in the `__lt__, __le__, __gt__, __ge__, __ne__, __eq__` methods?

Comment: Thanks for linking that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comparison is [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).  If you read the definition of that, you will understand everything.

Iterate the pairs of elements in order, and the first non-equal pair determines the winner of the ordering.

Comment: And, if all comparable elements are equal, the longer one is greater iirc.

Answer (score 1):

It's comparing them naively, i.e. element by element. 4 > 3, but 2 > 1.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  This isn't consistent with the second example.

Comment: @mortonjt: 1 == 1, 2 > 1

Comment: Right on, but 3 < 4?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The comparison has already been determined.

Comment: It compares them much like strings, except element by element rather than character by character. "bull" is less than "car" even though the second letter of "car" is less than the second letter of "bull". The first letter is enough in this case to make the decision. You only need to consider the second letters if the first letters are the same.